# Determining index of clicked element inside UL

Tags: jquery, navigation, html-lists

i wrote an UL-based navigation widget which uses links inside the LI-elements.
here's the task: when clicking a link i'd like to get the indexes like:

"you clicked link 5/10 on UL 2/4"

any ideas what's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Please stop writing tags in titles, and signing posts. Also after over 2 years on Stack Overflow and 226 questions posted, you should know by now that the English word "I" is capitalised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a hint. Check this out =>

HTML

```
<ul>
     <li>1</li>
     <li>2</li>
     <li>3</li>
     <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

And js:

```
$("ul li").click(function() {
    alert("You're clicked " + ($(this).index() + 1) + "/" + $("li", $(this).parent()).length)
});
```

demo on: http://jsfiddle.net/UcjHU/1/

Comment: Can you add your code here to make it a future-useful answer?